# СПП с придаточным уступки?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

*Всю-то ноченьку путешествовали вояки по боевым порядкам воюющих стран, несмотря на то, что передний край был с той и с другой стороны заминирован.*

СПП расчлененной структуры, придаточное уступки?

Comment: Анна, думаю, что нет смысла задавать однотипные вопросы по-одному. Можно, как вариант, привести весь перечень, а мы его проверим.

Comment: Хорошо, я учту.

Comment: Спасибо за понимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всю-то ноченьку путешествовали вояки по боевым порядкам воюющих стран, несмотря на то что передний край был с той и с другой стороны заминирован.

СПП расчлененной структуры, придаточное уступки, только одна запятая лишняя.

Здесь факультативное расчленение союза НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО ЧТО.

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы: это придаточное уступки расчлененной структуры. Придаточное предложение относится ко всему главному.